# How are these expressions for blackbody spectral energy density established?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, refraction, atmospheric-science

My first question regarding the following is: given that it is very
close to 1 in the atmosphere, do we really need to consider the index
of refraction in this context?

In the article Radiation and [Heat Transfer in the Atmosphere: A Comprehensive Approach on a Molecular Basis](https://doi.org/10.1155/2013/503727), byHermann Harde, we are given the
spectral **energy density** $u_{\lambda}$ (units: $J/m^{3}/\mu m$)

$$
u_{\lambda}=\frac{8\pi\mathit{n}^{4}hc}{\lambda^{5}}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\mathit{k}T\lambda}-1},
$$

or as a function of frequency

$$
u_{\nu}=u_{\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{2}}{cn}=\frac{8\pi\mathit{n}^{3}h\nu^{3}}{c^{3}}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/\mathit{k}T}-1}.
$$

Were $n$ is the index of refraction.

Carrying out the multiplication using $\lambda\nu=c,$ and leaving
out the exponential term, we get

$$
\left(\frac{8\pi\mathit{n}^{4}hc}{\lambda^{5}}\right)\frac{\lambda^{2}}{cn}=\frac{8\pi\mathit{n}^{3}h}{\lambda^{3}}=\frac{8\pi\mathit{n}^{3}h\nu^{3}}{c^{3}}.
$$

But this seems wrong since the speed of light will be $c/n.$ So we
should have $\lambda=c/n\nu.$ Thus I expect to have the equation

$$
\frac{8\pi h}{\lambda^{3}}=\frac{8\pi h\mathit{n}^{3}\nu^{3}}{c^{3}}.
$$

**Can someone explain how the above formulae for spectral energy density were established?**

I tried to figure it out starting with the expression for blackbody
radiation I am already familiar with. From the [Feynman Lectures on
Physics Volume I](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_41.html#Ch41-S3) we have the **incident intensity** of light for blackbody
radiation given in eq. 41.16 as

$$
\mathcal{I}\left(\omega\right)d\omega=\frac{\hbar\omega^{3}d\omega}{\pi^{2}c^{2}\left(e^{\hbar\omega/\mathit{k}T}-1\right)}.
$$

Substituting with $\omega/2\pi=\nu=c/\lambda$ and $\hbar\omega=h\nu=hc/\lambda$
we obtain equivalent expressions for $\mathcal{I}\left(\omega\right)$

$$
\left(\frac{\omega}{\pi c}\right)^{2}=\frac{4\nu^{2}}{c^{2}}=\frac{4}{\lambda^{2}},
$$
$$
\frac{\hbar\omega^{3}}{\pi^{2}c^{2}}=\frac{4h\nu^{3}}{c^{2}}=\frac{4hc}{\lambda^{3}},
$$
$$
\mathcal{I}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{\hbar\omega^{3}}{\pi^{2}c^{2}}\frac{1}{e^{\hbar\omega/\mathit{k}T}-1}=\frac{4h\nu^{3}}{c^{2}}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/\mathit{k}T}-1}=\frac{4hc}{\lambda^{3}}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\mathit{k}T\lambda}-1}.
$$

These are related to the expressions found in the article as follows

$$
u_{\lambda}=\frac{2\pi n^{4}}{\lambda^{2}}\mathcal{I}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{2\pi n^{4}}{\lambda^{2}}\left(\frac{4hc}{\lambda^{3}}\frac{1}{e^{hc/\mathit{k}T\lambda}-1}\right),
$$

$$
u_{\nu}=\frac{2\pi n^{3}}{c}\mathcal{I}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{2\pi n^{3}}{c}\left(\frac{4h\nu^{3}}{c^{2}}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/\mathit{k}T}-1}\right).
$$

What Feynman gives is a surface intensity.  The expression in the article are energy densities. I'm assuming that's why they differ.

---

Adding: I believe this may come from the classical wave and energy equations which in vacuum involve $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_o \mu_o}}$.

Using the formula relating speed of light in matter to the index of refraction of the material, along with the expression for the permittivity $\varepsilon$ of the material in terms of vacuum permittivity $\varepsilon_o$ and the dielectric constant $\kappa$ of the material, we obtain a relationship between the average energy density $\langle\mathcal{W}\rangle$ of a harmonic plane wave in vacuum with amplitude $E_o,$ and that of a harmonic plane wave of the same frequency and amplitude in the material $\langle\mathcal{W}_n\rangle$ (using continuity conditions at the material interface in the case of a solid medium).

$$\begin{align}\frac{c}{n}=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon\mu_{o}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\kappa\varepsilon_{o}\mu_{o}}}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\kappa}}\\
\kappa=&n^2\\
\langle\mathcal{W}_n\rangle=&\frac{\varepsilon}{2}E_o^2=\frac{\kappa\varepsilon_o}{2}E_o^2=n^2
\langle\mathcal{W}\rangle
\end{align}.$$

I haven't worked out the rest.  This just came to mind while reading a discussion of electromagnetic waves interacting with a glass pane, so I wanted to record the thought.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is your third equation?  Carrying out what multiplication?   Also, it's not clear that you are taking into account that the functions in question are *densities*.    I don't see how you take that into account.  (I.e., did you do the right thing with $\mathrm{d}\lambda$ and $\mathrm{d}\nu$)  You may have done everything perfectly correctly.   But to me (at least) I can't follow it; consequently don't know what the question is.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Did you read the equations? The ones prior to the question "Can someone explain how the above formulae for spectral energy density were established?"  That came from the article I linked, and it's pretty much as provided.  The second equation is the product of the first equation with a given factor.  I just carried out that multiplication to show that it produces the advertised result.   I posted the stuff based on the Feynman Lectures to explain the extent to which I have attempted to figure out how the expressions in the article were established.